# Dangers/side-effects of using PHP's ternary operator as a control structure

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

A coworker frequently uses PHP's ternary operator as a control structure, rather than the RHS of an expression. One such example:

```
list==''?list=val:list=list+','+val;
```

(In that example, the statement is called in a loop to add values to a string, ensuring the comma separator doesn't appear if there's only one item.) In essence, he relies on the expression evaluation to do work, and throws away the expression result.

Aside from the fact that it's hard on the eyes, is there any reason to avoid this construct? It's syntactically legal; and it executes correctly. But I'm certain the ternary operator wasn't designed to be used in this manner, and I wonder if there are consequences to doing so.

Comment: "*But I'm certain the ternary operator wasn't designed to be used in this manner*" Can you provide any material on this? (I'm interested)

Comment: _"Aside from the fact that it's hard on the eyes"_. To my mind it's the only problem.

Comment: If you are assigning to the same variable in both branches, a-la `x?a=b:a=c`, you are repeating yourself and there's the risk of assigning to the wrong variable. This risk is of course reduced by intellisense and other conveniences, but it's still not very DRY.

Comment: 'Aside from the fact that it's hard on the eyes' I think is a valid concern for avoiding it.

Comment: What are the consequences of being an idiot? That depends on the team, but generally there are none. Sad but true.

Comment: In the first place, this is not a valid php statement. It looks like javascript unless your php concatenation operator is `+`. Mine is still ".". I'll rather write it like this: `list = list==''?val:list.','.val`;

Comment: @Peter, you're totally right, I typed it out from memory.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ : Essentially, because it's defined as an operator, not a control structure. Every single example of ?: use in the PHP manual treats it as an operator used to build the RHS of an assignment expression. If the designers also intended it to be used as a control structure, I'd expect to see a reference to that usage on the manual pages for if{} and else{}

Answer (score 3):

It will work fine, and I don't see any problem with it apart from readability.

If you think it's hard on the eyes, replace this loop and line with a call to the `implode` function.